# HTML elements in XML documents

Tags: html, xml, specifications

I've been reading the HTML specifciation and I am confused with this [line](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#elements-in-the-dom):

> The nodes representing HTML elements in the DOM must implement, and
>   expose to scripts, the interfaces listed for them in the relevant
>   sections of this specification. **This includes HTML elements in XML
>   documents**

What HTML elements have to do with xml documents? Somewhat vague [description](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#xml) makes things even more complicated:

> To ease migration from HTML to XML, UAs conforming to this
>   specification will place elements in HTML in the
>   http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml namespace, at least for the purposes of
>   the DOM and CSS. The term "HTML elements" refers to any element in
>   that namespace, even in XML documents.

What kind of migration? Who is UA? What is this http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml namespace? How can URL be a namespace? And again, what HTML elements have to do with XML document?

Comment: A namespace is the schema (the rules) for a set of xml tags.  Often the schema is on a URL.  There is a default xml namespace and you can have additional schema for any xml.  You can have embedded xml inside an HTML.

Comment: Thanks! What's the purpose of the namespaces? Are there any resources to find out how they work?

Comment: The namespace are the schema (rules) for required elements and the allowable values of the elements.